# Boost test fixture parameter

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test, parametrized-testing

I want to write a parametrised unit test using boost::test. Preferably I'd like to pass parameters to my fixture class. I write multiple test cases with the same setup and tear-down scenarios, so it'd be pretty handy. Unfortunately, I'm aware that the boost::test framework assumes that the fixture class has a zero-constructor. So I can't see any way to pass the test parameter inside the fixture class.

Do you have any idea how could I properly design my test?

My only guess is to use `BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_F` and call some helper method inside a test body. More or less something like this:

```cpp
struct Fixture
{
    Fixture( void ) 
    {
       // initialise 'zombie' fixture
    }

    void set_up( int parameter )
    {
        // common init with parameter
        // fixture is fully functional now
    }
};

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE_F(
    Fixture, 
    DummyTest, 
    boost::unit_test::data::make<int>( { 1,2,3 } )
)
{
  set_up( sample ); // `sample` variable is provided by boost::test
  BOOST_TEST(true);
}
```

However, I don't like the idea of adding the `set_up` method at the beginning of each test. Maybe in boost, there's some hidden feature that I could re-use in this case?

Comment: Doesn't `BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE` without `_F` work?

Comment: The fixtures are by design independent of the parameters of the test cases, so to answer your question, there will no be any clean design using Boost.Test in the current implementation.